# Best Way to Get State from Redux Store in Action Creator

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

My store looks like this:

```
{
    nodes: {
        node1: { childIds: [], },
        node2: { childIds: [], },
    },
    selectedNode: 'node1',
}
```

I have a ADD_CHILD action like so:

```
export function addChild(parentId, childId) {
  return {
    type: ADD_CHILD,
    parentId,
    childId,
  };
}
```

The reducer adds the childId under the parentId object's childIds. So, `addChild('node1', 'node2')` results in this state:

```
{
    nodes: {
        node1: { childIds: ['node2'], },
        node2: { childIds: [], },
    },
    selectedNode: 'node1',
}
```

So far so good.

**What I'd like to do, is have the parentId parameter be optional in my action creator. I'd like my logic to automatically default parentId as the `selectedNode` value from the store if it's not specified to the action creator.**

What is the best practice method of defaulting to a value from the store? Options I can think of:

1. Use Redux-thunk, or similar, to access the state in my action creator and pull the selectedNode value there. I'm leaning towards this method... I don't see many downsides, other than expanding the amount of logic in my action creator.
2. Expand my nodes reducer to cover more area of the state, including the selectedNode into the state it receives. I don't like this as it adds complexity to the reducer and puts interface state into my node data.
3. Use mapStateToProps to tell my Component about the selectedNode value as a prop, so when it calls the action creator it can pass it along. I don't like this because it will cause my component to re-render any time the selectedNode changes (and this component otherwise doesn't need to do this).

Are there other options? I'm mainly interested in best practice, as I think any of these methods will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you take a look at [`reduce-reducers`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reduce-reducers).

The well-known `combineReducers()` that Redux provides runs reducers in parallel, if you will, with each reducer only being aware of the piece of state within its own scope. *Other configurations of reducers are possible.* For example, you could *reduce an array of reducers*, running each in *series*, meaning that each will get a freshly computed state object from its precursors to use to compute the new state that it will pass on.

In your case, this would allow your reducer to know about `selectedNode` while reducing your `ADD_CHILD` action. If the `parentId` is not set in the action, the reducer can default to `selectedNode`. You just have to make sure that the reducer that changes `selectedNode` runs *upstream* of the one handling `ADD_CHILD`.

This covered in a nice way (with examples) in the Redux docs [Redux docs: sharing-data-between-slice-reducers](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/beyond-combinereducers#sharing-data-between-slice-reducers).

Using this pattern will allow you to avoid thunks, maintain simple action creators, still have simple component selectors, keep your state logic in the reducers where it belongs, and still keep your reducers pure. Having tried most of those other patterns you mentioned myself, I recommend this approach.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Ian - very well described. That sounds like a clean method.